# How to clear database sessions pool after making request

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I'm trying to use FastAPI with async SQLAlchemy. For db session I want to create FastApi dependency:

```py
async_db_url = f'postgresql+asyncpg://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}'
async_engine = create_async_engine(async_db_url)
async_session = sessionmaker(async_engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)


async def async_db_session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        except Exception as exc:
            await session.rollback()
            raise exc
```

I expect that the session will be closed after use, because of context manager. But it does not happen. Instead of that I can see new connections with each request. And number of connections riches the limit, I can't connect to db anymore.

I tried to use  `engine.dispose()` from [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html), but it caused very slow requests. I did it like that:

```py
async def async_db_session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    async with async_session() as session:
        try:
            yield session
        except Exception as exc:
            await session.rollback()
            raise exc
        finally:
            await engine.dispose()
```

How to force connection to drop after making a request?

Comment: try this maybe? https://pastebin.com/G4gW4JPC

Comment: @Andrew problem has been solved with updating of asyncpg lib to latest version

Comment: i use last version asyncpg. the problem was not solved.